# Algorithm to combine similar hashes in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

The question is mostly in the title:

given an array

```
array = [{x: 1, y: "jacksonville"}, 
        {x: 2, y: "atlanta"}, 
        {x: 1, y: "tampa"}, 
        {x: 2, y: "atlanta"},
        {x: 2, y: "jacksonville"},
        {x: 2, y: "miami"}, ]
```

Whats a good method to attain the following result

```
array = [{x: 3, y: "jacksonville",
         {x: 4, y: "atlanta"},
         {x: 1, y: "tampa"},
         {x: 2 ,y: "miami"}]
```

The input are a simplistic version of what i'm really working with but as you can see i'm attempting to remove duplicates of the y values but retain the x values, I know i can run a merge on each hash combining two hashes by passing a black to Hash#merge but i'm having difficulty comparing all hashes to each other or finding the duplicates. Looking for a performant solution.

Comment: Iteration is pretty much the answer. There's no magic method, just loop over your input array, and build your output array.

Comment: Shouldn't the x key be 4 for `y: 'atlanta'`?

Comment: @depa good looking out

Comment: Unless you have performance concerns, data modeled like this is really screaming out for a class with some methods to handle merging.  This isn't an answer, but before you go with one of the more-efficient-but-unreadable quick solutions, consider creating a nicer data structure for the benefit of maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
array.group_by{|e|e[:y]}.map{|k,v|{x:v.reduce(0){|a,b|a+b[:x]},y:k}}
```

Comment: I wouldn't obsess with writing a one-liner (that way you could throw some spaces there and find better names for the variables), but that's the way to go.

Comment: this is really nice but I'll have 2 keys I'll be comparing against, I figured my sample data was good enough to get a general ida.

Comment: @TheIrishGuy `array.group_by{|e| [e[:y], e[:z]]}...` takes care of 2 keys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must have to create a convenient way to index y data. I would use Hash for that:

```
h = array.inject({}) do |ret, item|
   ret[item[:y]] ||= 0 # initialize each item
   ret[item[:y]] += item[:x] # increment count
   ret # return the hash
end
```

With this Hash on hand, you can generate the new array:

```
h.map {|key, value| {x: value, y: key}}
```